# IntelliJ IDEA TestNG output console clears

Tags: intellij-idea, testng

I have test with 3 test methods.
In output console I can see only data from the last run test method. Previous tests outputs are cleared.

Is it possible to see outputs of all test methods?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a tree of tests displayed on the left of the panel, click on the root to see the output of all the tests or click on the specific tests to see their output.

Comment: Tree was hided. Thank you for tip.