# Intellij IDEA Console Logging Truncated With TestNG Run/Debug Configuration

Tags: java, intellij-idea, selenium-webdriver, testng

For some reason Intellij IDEA's 'save console output to file' option in run/debug configurations gets truncated for my TestNG test runs. Other posters have pointed out that to actually see the console output for all the tests, you have to drill down on the tree in the IDEA Run window, click + on package, click + on test class, etc. then click on each test method to see it's console output.

EG:
[IntelliJ IDEA TestNG output console clears](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14683800/intellij-idea-testng-output-console-clears)

And:
[Intellij not shows test results in console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20395416/intellij-not-shows-test-results-in-console)

However I don't see a post anywhere explaining how to actually log all of this to one log file. And I really don't get why IDEA must break up one test run's console outs to so many places in the tree, seems kind of silly.

Anyway, all I'm getting in the log file is my initialization class output, but nothing from any of the subsequent tests (drilled further down in the tree). Any suggestions how to make IDEA logging work with TestNG much appreciated.

Comment: In Short all I want is to somehow get Intellij IDEA to log all console output to one log file. The answer below though detailed does not help. Still, all method System.out.println() calls are still missing, and only suite level logging is working in IDEA.

Answer (score 3):

> I really don't get why IDEA must break up one test run's console outs to so many places in the tree, seems kind of silly.

The intent is so you can see output relevant to a specific test. This way, when running dozens, or hundreds, of tests, you can focus on the relevant output and not a lot of "noise" that is irrelevant to the the particular test you are focusing on.

> However I don't see a post anywhere explaining how to actually log all of this to one log file.

This is typically done via your logging framework, not the IDE. (But there is a way to do this in IDEA w/o a logging framework, which I discuss below.) As an aside, Logback is ideal for this since it automatically looks for a test specific configuration file. Of course, with other frameworks, you can set a test specific configuration file.

If you create a run/debug configuration for running your test, you can add the log file's output to a tab in the run output tool window. In your run/debug configuration, click on the `Logs` tab and add the log that your logging framework writes to. You can also set it up so that only new/fresh output is shown in the tab preventing you from seeing logging from previous runs.

You can also select the "Save Console Output to File" option.

Finally, you can combine the above two settings, so that console output is logged to a file, and the output is shown in a second tab.

If you want either of the settings to to be the default, you can set it in the default "unit test" configuration. Expand the "Default" section in the Run/Debug configuration window (*Run > Edit Configurations*). When set there, any new run/debug unit test configurations (even temporary ones created on the fly via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>) will have those settings. Note that defaults only apply to the current project.  If you want to make the setting a global default for all future projects, From the Welcome Screen (i.e. close all projects) go to "Configure" > *"Project Defaults" > "Run Configurations"* and make the setting there.

Comment: Mark, thanks for the feedback. Maybe you missed my comment 'save console output to file' so I'm already using your suggestion in run configurations :) And I've got logging working in reporting with testNG... What I'm looking to do is create a separate log file with all of the console data, at all levels (suite/class/method) concatenated together into one log file.

Comment: And yes, I get why each method needs its own console output separated so you can click on that method and see it's own output, but I don't get why IDEA puts only the suite level initialization output in the log from 'save console output to file'. Is Logback a solution for this? Thanks again for your detailed response.

Answer (score 1):

There's an [old bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-72036) affecting IDEA's *TestNG* support. It doesn't matter whether you're looking at the console output or logging to a file -- the output is truncated anyway. Feel free to vote up: maybe they will fix it eventually.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you cannot run unit test successfully (due to exceptions, not expected results, bugs). The output will be in console once your unit test gets run successfully.

I know that adding system output in console helps you to debug via unit tests, but unfortunately IntelliJ doesn't support it.